# I am trying to make a simple replying bot on discord with discord.py however I am getting this error and Im not sure why

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The thing thats weird is that, I dont even have 343 lines of code, I only have like 30, so I'm really not sure why this is happening

The error :

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aiosdj\PycharmProjects\nerdeyes\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/aiosdj/PycharmProjects/nerdeyes/main.py", line 28, in on_message
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, msg)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

The code :

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.nerd ', description = 'nerd eyes')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    guild_count = 0

    for guild in bot.guilds:

        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")

        guild_count = guild_count + 1

    print('Nerdeyes has awoken in ' + str(guild_count) + " servers")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('.nerd'):
        msg = 'eyes'.format(message)
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, msg)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bot.send_message` doesn't exist, which is what your error also says. You need something that implements [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=messageable#discord.abc.Messageable), like a `Channel`, `User`, or `Member` - and the method is called `send`, not `send_message`. A quick look at the [API docs for `Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) also shows that this method is nowhere to be found. It's generally not a bad idea to first check if a method exists before using it.

```py
await message.channel.send(msg)
```

Also, `msg = 'eyes'.format(message)` - the `.format` here does nothing at all, this is the same as just `'eyes'`.

> I dont even have 343 lines of code

The error says it happens in **\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py line 343**, not *your* file. This is a line in the Discord library, which your code calls, so at one point or another one of those methods will crash. The line *below* in the error says which line of yours it comes from (28).

ps. You just leaked your bot token, generate a new one.